# Why doesn't DOM style object set CSS variables directly?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

My understanding is there are two equivalent ways to set CSS rules via JavaScript:

```
#1: element.style.setProperty(propertyName, value)

#2: element.style.propertyName = value
```

I have always favored the second, shorter method.

When it comes to CSS variables, I find I have to use an explicit setProperty call:

```
element.style.setProperty('--varName', value)
```

This approach has no effect on variables:

```
element.style['--varName'] = value
```

Why is this?

Comment: Here's my guess... but it's just a guess. The way `style` works is very simple in that it overrides all styles from stylesheets *(setting aside `!important`)*. Because CSS variables need to consider the scope of the variable, I'm guessing that `setProperty()` simply does more background work, determining which stylesheet contains the rule that has highest priority, and/or analysing the scope of the given variable. I suppose they could make a default `:root` scope, but apparently did not. Again, just a guess.

Comment: ...you may find your answer in the specification for `setProperty`.

Comment: Here's [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty) for `setProperty()`. You can see that it has a step specifically to deal with a "custom property", which is [spec'd here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables-1/#custom-property), and defined as *"any property whose name starts with two dashes"*. So the `setProperty()` method is specifically designed to deal with CSS vars. I'm *guessing* the `style` setter is not spec'd to handle it, but I haven't looked yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's because DOM's Style function only understands HTML properties and not CSS properties. Defining CSS properties are listed in style's setProperty Function.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. There are no HTML properties involving style, aside from a few, very specific ones tied to specific elements. In what way is `style.backgroundImage` an HTML property, and not CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The `.style[propertyName]` expects a **property name** inside but does not support a **custom property** like `.setProperty()` does. If you pass `--varName`, you are passing the **value** assigned to the brackets.

For example, if `--varName: 'blue'`, by saying `.style['--varName'] = value`, you are saying ****change the blue property**** to value. Since **blue is not a property**, it will not work.

Comment: Saying *it should work* doesn't really give an answer. If it worked, I doubt the OP would be asking the question. Can you give an example showing it working? The `--varName` syntax is for setting and accessing CSS variables.

Comment: what goes inside the brackets is the property name and not the value of the element. If --varName equals 'blue' for example, it won't work cuz blue is not a property but a value

Comment: The first argument to `setProperty` is also the property name, and he stated that it works there. Seems that he's trying to set a new variable, and is wondering why it can't be done with `.style[...]` syntax.

Comment: The .style[...] expects a property name inside not a value. If you pass `--varName`, you are passing the value to the brackets. If `--varName: 'blue'`, by saying `.style['--varName'] = value`, you are saying change the blue property to value. Since blue is not a property, it will not work.

Comment: `.setProperty` also expects a property name, and it works when using `"--varName"`. This is because `"--varName"` is a property name when defining the variable. He's not trying to use the value; he's trying to *set* the value to that variable name.

Comment: I know OP wasn' trying to use the value but `.style` cannot interpret the custom property the same way like `setProperty`. When you pass a `--varName`to  `setProperty`, it will update the value. The `style` property cannot do that

Comment: The `.style` doesn't use the value of the variable as the property name. It uses `"--varName"` as the property name. But his question is why one works when the other doesn't. In other words, why would they make `.setProperty()` behave as expeccted, but not `.style[...]`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to retrieve it from  [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#Values_in_JavaScript

> To use the values of custom properties in JavaScript, it is just like standard properties.
>
> ---
>
> // get variable from inline style
>
> element.style.getPropertyValue("--my-var");
>
> ---
>
> // get variable from wherever
>
> getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--my-var");
>
> ---
>
> // set variable on inline style
>
> element.style.setProperty("--my-var", jsVar + 4);

```js
document.body.style.setProperty('--varName', 'see i got stored even i`m a useless value');
let root = window.getComputedStyle(document.body );
let varNameValue= root.getPropertyValue('--varName');
console.log(varNameValue);
```

Comment: He's asking why using `.style["--varName"]` doesn't work, when `.setProperty` does.

Comment: @slappy it cannot work because this is not a valid syntax i guess , that's the way to do it properly.

Comment: Yes, it does seem that they didn't allow that syntax for `style`. The question is why they allowed it in one place and not the other. It's actually an interesting question.

Comment: took me a while to find a proper link ;)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#Values_in_JavaScript